# Mojo application token, what is it?

Tags: networking, 16.04

I'm trying to understand what is it and why does it send information over the internet? I have searched the internet for the answer but nothing came up that would completely answer my question

it looks something like this on nethogs:

```
--mojo-application-channel-token=07627B2F0D6C64665F60A06B8D175289
```

It is being used by my username, no ip or port included, just sending and receiving up to 500kb of information. Thanks for your answers in advance.

**EDIT:** I managed to get a snippet of the last part of the token while it was in action. Couldn't resize more...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be related to this project: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/mojo/README.md. It looks like an developer/IPC/debugging method that chrome and v8-based webkits use (like [Electron](https://github.com/electron), or [NW.js](https://nwjs.io/)).

I think, you probably had a development version of some app running that you weren't aware of.

Comment: Thanks for the late answer.  All I can remember is that it stopped when I removed sublime text but I'm unsure whether or not it was related.

Comment: Sublime might be chromium/v8-powered, but I couldn't tell for sure when I installed it and I didn't break open the binaires to find out. BTW: I only answered because I had a similar question myself, since I saw records of mojo-application-channel-tokens being used on my system as well.